# Spring Controller ambiguous mapping error

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm setting up a RestController in Spring, and I have an ambiguous mapping issue. I don't see how the last two methods are ambiguous, because the request mappings and method names are different. When I remove the method specification from the last method, the issue isn't there anymore.

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping({"/comment/ait/"})
public class AitController extends BaseController {

```
@Autowired
private AitService aitService;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"addAit"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public int addAit(CommentAitVo aitVo, @RequestParam(name = "commentType") CommentType commentType) {
    aitVo.setCommentType(commentType.value);
    aitVo.setCreateuserid(getUserId());
    aitVo.setCreatetime(new Date());
    return aitService.addCommentAit(aitVo);
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"readedAit"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public int readedAit(@RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) {
    return aitService.readedCommentAit(id);
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"delAit"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public int delAit(@RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) {
    return aitService.delCommentAit(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"getAitList"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public List<CommentAitVo> getAitList(@RequestParam(name = "receiverId") String receiverId, PageQuery query) {
    return aitService.getCommentAitRecordList(query, receiverId).getList();
}
```

}

which results in this error:

```
RequestID: 2018-05-24 17:51:30.753 WARN  [main] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext [?] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'aitController' method 
public java.util.List<com.meicloud.saas.comment.vo.CommentAitVo> com.meicloud.saas.comment.console.controller.AitController.getAitList(java.lang.String,com.meicloud.paas.core.beans.PageQuery)
to {[/saas-api/comment/ait/getAitList],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'com.meicloud.saas.comment.console.controller.AitController#0' bean method
```